# Can amazon s3 bucket be used for queues?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I have an amazon s3 bucket and I want to implement SQS using this bucket. Is that possible? Or do i need another placeholder for it altogether? Following is the code I use to read from queue.

```
ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest();
receiveMessageRequest.QueueUrl = url;
ReceiveMessageResponse receiveMessageResponse = client.ReceiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest);
```

Comment: Queue? for what? All I know S3 is for simple object storage.

Comment: Could you please Edit your question to provide more information about what you are trying to accomplish? For example, how do you intend to use Amazon S3? Do you wish to store a file in S3, then store a message in an SQS queue that references that file, so that a later process that grabs that message will know to download and use the file from S3? The more details you can provide, the better the chance of receiving a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use lambda functions. When and item is put in s3 you can configure a lambda function that gets triggered. This can put an item in SQS.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html

Comment: So I can use the SQS functions to, say, download a file from this queue?

Comment: Its upto you to do what you want with the file thereafter

Comment: I guess my question is....can we combine both bucket and queue? When I upload a file to a bucket, do i then have to move it explicitly into a queue to be downloaded or can i use the queue operations to download the file from the bucket itself?

Answer (score 1):

Right now the S3 bucket event notifications can be published to SQS.

[image]